# Lambda Function Error (Mapbox Asset-Tracking)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, mapbox

I am trying to replicate Mapbox's asset tracking solution found here:
https://github.com/mapbox/asset-tracking

Everything goes fine until this:

```js
aws:lambda:Function (mapboxQuery4c238266):
    error: Error creating Lambda function: InvalidParameterValueException: The runtime parameter of nodejs8.10 is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs12.x) while creating or updating functions.
        status code: 400, request id: 286685ae-520e-45d4-a5ba-a546f50e9d3d
```

I can't find that function in the main index.js or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the problem. There was only ONE bit of code that specifically requested version 12. The rest of the code only requires Nodejs 8. I went ahead and changed that requirement and it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Per the error message, you should make sure your node version is at least version 12. You can check this with the `node -v` command and then update accordingly.